# Get the hidden text to the top of my container

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I have a `div#content` with property `overflow:scroll;` and I want to show the hidden text at the begining of my `div#content` when I click on a button.

I have tried in my `onClick` function handler:

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("contenido");
objDiv.scrollTop = 540;
```

Where `540` is my `div#content` height.

I works perfectly when I have many lines of hidden text but if I have one line of hidden text this code will not place that last line on the top of my div.

Is there any way to get the hidden text to the top of my container?

Comment: @panther:[link](http://goo.gl/QMA81Z) This includes the "div-solution" sugested by RobG. If you remove the div after text and click the button till the end you will see the whole text but the very last line will not be at the begining of my container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, a div will only scroll as far as it needs to get the last line into view. If you only have one line of content, it can't scroll to 540px because there's nothing to scroll to. e.g. the following works fine:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('d1').scrollTop = 100">scroll</button>

<div id="d1" style="height: 100px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;
 overflow:scroll;">Lorem ipsumin eros scelerisque commodo non id nisi. Ut
 porta non eros eget malesuada. Curabitur adipiscing bibendum sapien quis
 porta. Nam ac dui a quam aliquet volutpat. Curabitur ac mi quam. Fusce
 consectetur, ipsum sed venenatis feugiat, ligula leo luctus neque, ac
 rutrum sapien erat ac mi. Aliquam nulla leo, gravida sit amet velit nec, 
 commodo bibendum lacus. Quisque sapien risus, aliquet nec nisl et, sodales
 ullamcorper risus. In porttitor justo id  pellentesque sollicitudin.
 Quisque sodales purus non felis iaculis tincidunt. Vestibulum urna metus,
 mattis in</div>
```

because there is enough content for it to scroll. Reduce the content to a couple of words (or increase the scroll to say 2000) and it won't scroll all the way because there's no content to scroll that far.

If you want it to scroll further, put aother div inside that extends at least 540px beyond the content, or add "blank" content to extend the scrollable area.

Comment: Thank you so much @RobG. I tried with div approach and works perfecty. Here is my implementation: [link](http://goo.gl/QMA81Z).